# Buttons in jQuery Impromptu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a survey composition tool. The preview button should show a preview of values entered by the user.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/Impromptu/src/jquery-impromptu.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/rabbit.css"/>

    <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
    <script src = "../plugins/Impromptu/src/jquery-impromptu.js"></script>

    <title> Survey Composition tool </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="nav">
        <h2>Widgets</h2>

        <ul id="navUl">
          <li id = "chooseRadio"> <input type = "radio"> <h4> Radio </h4> </li>
          <li id = "chooseCheckbox"> <input type = "checkbox"> <h4> Checkbox</h4></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id = "main">
        <div id = "heading">
          <h1><label>  Survey Title: </label></h1> 
          <input type="text" id="title" value="Dining Experience Survey"/>
          <button id = "preview">Preview</button>
      </div>

      <div id="radio">
        <ul id="radioUl">
          <li id = "radioClose"> X </li>
          <li class = "type"> <h3>Radio</h3> </li>           
          <li> <input type="text" value="Did you enjoy your dining experience?" class="radioInput1"/> </li>
          <li> <input type="text" value="Yes" class="radioInput2"/> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="checkbox">
        <ul id="checkboxUl">
          <li id = "checkboxClose"> X </li>
          <li><h3>Checkbox</h3></li>
          <li> <input type="text" value="What did you order (Check all that apply)?" class="checkboxInput"/> </li>
          <li> <input type="text" value="Blueberry Pie, Cherry Peppers, Cheese Crab Dip, Shrimp Quesadillas" class="checkboxInput"/> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src = "../javascript/rabbit.js"></script> 

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 40px auto;
    height: 547px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#nav {
    width: 140px;
    height: 550px;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

h2{
    margin: 3px 25px 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

#navUl {
    padding-left: 21px;
}

#navUl li {
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

h4 {
    display: inline;
}

#main {
    clear:both;
    margin-top: -530px;
}

#heading {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 160px;
    margin-bottom: 400px;
}

h1 {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-before:0px;
    -webkit-margin-after:0px;
}

#title {
    height: 35px;
    width: 475px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#preview {
    padding-top: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 3px solid lightgray;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px black;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#radio {
    float:right;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -360px;
    margin-right: 45px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#radioClose, #checkboxClose {
    float: right;
}

.radioInput1, .radioInput2 {
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 700px;
}

#radioUl li {
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

#checkbox {
    float:right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -160px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin-right: 45px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.checkboxInput {
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 700px;
}

#checkboxUl li {
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

Javascript

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var chooseRadio = $("#chooseRadio");
    var radio = $("#radio");
    var chooseCheckbox = $("#chooseCheckbox");
    var checkbox = $("#checkbox");
    var radioClose = $("#radioClose");
    var checkboxClose = $("#checkboxClose");
    var button = $('button');

    chooseRadio.on("click",function () {
        radio.toggle();
    });

    chooseCheckbox.on("click",function () {
        checkbox.toggle();
    });

    chooseRadio.on("mouseover",function () {
        chooseRadio.css('cursor','pointer');
    });

    chooseCheckbox.on("mouseover",function () {
        chooseCheckbox.css('cursor','pointer');
    });

    radioClose.on("click",function () {
        radio.hide();
    });

    checkboxClose.on("click",function () {
        checkbox.hide();
    });

    radioClose.on("mouseover",function () {
        radioClose.css("cursor","pointer");
    });

    checkboxClose.on("mouseover",function () {
        checkboxClose.css("cursor","pointer");
    });

    button.on("click",function () {
        button.css("cursor","pointer");
        $.prompt($('.radioInput1').val(), {
            title: "Survey",
            buttons: { "Yes" : true, "No" : false, "Not Sure" :false }
        });
    });

}) (jQuery);
```

I do not understand why the following code is not working. Is there a way to output values the user entered instead of hard-coding Yes, No and Not Sure in the buttons object of jquery Impromptu?

```
$.prompt($('.radioInput1').val(), {
                title: "Survey",
                buttons: { $('.radioInput1').val() : true, "No" : false, "Not Sure" :false }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can safely use jQuery you need to ensure that the page is in a state where it's ready to be manipulated.$( document ).ready(function() {} help us achieve that.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, here is what solved it for me.

Try commenting out the `use strict` lines in your javascript, and the same line in the plugin itself:

```
"use strict";
```

(Note: there is a "use strict" line in the plug-in itself as well.)